# Button for checkbox worked once

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox

I have created checkboxes. When user checks an item, the item is displayed in datagridview.
This is the code of checkbox in XAML

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Name="APIList" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Tables[0]}"  
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NameColumnTemplate}" 
        SelectionChanged="lst_SelectionChanged" CheckBox.Click="lst_SelectionChanged"/>
    <Button Content="listbox" Name="btnShowSelectedItems" 
        Click="btnShowSelectedItems_Click" />
</Grid>
```

This is the code behind

```
 private void btnShowSelectedItems_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string path, name;
        int i = 0,c=0, result;
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\7th semester\FYP\source\repos\dllPaths.txt");
        string[] selecteditem = new string[50];
        var showapi = APIList.ItemsSource as List<showAPI>;
        foreach (var item in showapi)
        {
            if (item.IsSelected == true)
            {
                selecteditem[i] = item.apiName;
            }
        }
    }
```

When user click on button checked items display in table but if user again check more items and again click on button nothing happen and result remain unchanged. 
In short this button work only once.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Thanks, Kindly give me solution of my problem

Comment: Before your question can be answered, you need to follow StackOverflow's guidelines in @Bijan's link above- reduce the scope of the code so that it meets the minimal, complete, verifiable standards, and you will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: I can't give you a solution because your question does not match the standards of this site. note that we are not wizards! and we cannot guess what is going wrong unless you provide enough information regarding **a specific problem**. please read the link first and then update your question. I tried to remove parts of your code which seem irrelevant to the question to make a more readable question. however, there are still many necessary things you haven't included in the question yet

Comment: If you try clicking on something other than the button after the first click does the button work? If that is the case it could be a focus issue.

Comment: Nothing work after first click

Comment: can you show what you do with the selecteditem array after the click and/or show us how you display the table?